Selecting the Appropriate Anaconda Distribution for Installation
Previously, I had no trouble visiting the Anaconda website to download the software. But recently, when I went to Anaconda.com to obtain the latest version for a friend, I was presented with two options: ‘Students and Academics’ or ‘Practitioners and Hobbyists':

Both versions are exactly the same size (904.4 MB), but I’m unsure which one to download. On one hand, as a PhD and academic, I feel I should opt for the first option. On the other hand, as a hobbyist who loves machine learning, the second option also appeals to me. Could you clarify the exact differences between these two versions, and where these differences manifest? Additionally, if I install the academic version instead of the hobbyist one, will I be missing out on any important features?
I’ve searched the web, including YouTube, but all the explanations I’ve found refer to the old Anaconda website.

You can download either one, they are identical in terms of features and package distribution. You can also just use the download button at the very top of the page. You will get the same Anaconda with any of these options.

Do you have any link to a help page/FAQ that confirms this?

If you click on each option individually you will see that in both cases it just takes you to the top of the page which is the form to submit your email and get the distro (you don't have to provide your email and can skip to actual download)
